# Javascript: How to add RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a js code where it colors the table red/green by negative/positive values.
It works fine with 0.00 values, but not with 0,00 values.

I heard there is a possibility with RegExp, but I cant get it working.

Could someone please check. Thank you.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td'), $negative, $i;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $cells.length; $i++) {
        if ($cells[$i].className === 'negative' && 
        !isNaN($cells[$i].innerHTML)) {
        $negative = (1 * $cells[$i].innerHTML) < 0;
        $cells[$i].style.backgroundColor = $negative ? '#b22222' : '#00804f';
        $cells[$i].style.color           = $negative ? '#ffffff' : '#ffffff';
        }
     }
  </script>
```

Comment: you need to change `0,00` to `0.00` .do with `$cells[$i].innerHTML.replace(',','.')`

Answer (score 0):

If the value are incorrect because they have the wrong decimal delimiter in your culture.
You can remplace the delimiter with the correct one as @Prasad commented.

```
$cells[$i].innerHTML.replace(',','.')
```

Or convert your string to int with `parseInt()`.
And use the int value to check if it's positive.

```
$negative = parseInt($cells[$i].innerHTML) < 0;
```

From there you can even print it in the culture your want with `toLocaleString()`.